# Tail probabilities of geometric series of i.i.d. random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I've tried very hard to come up with a solution to this and both my manual efforts and a fair amount of research has not been able to solve it for me.

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=0}^\infty$ be i.i.d. random variables, and let $a>1$ be some constant. I define the "tail function" for the distribution as,
$$T(u) := P(|X_0| > u),\quad\forall u\geq 0.$$
Now I am interested in the following geometric series. We define the random variable $X$ by
$$X := \sum_{i=0}^\infty a^{-i}|X_i|.$$
which I believe is a valid random variable, no matter how the $X_i$ are identically distributed. Notably $X$ is nonnegative, and I am interested in the following question:

What is the sharpest bound I can place on $P(X > u)$ in terms of only the constant $a$ and the tail function $T(\cdot)$? Loosely speaking, when $a$ is large this tail behaviour should be very similar to that of $T(\cdot)$. But I would like to find a rigorous concentration bound to apply here, for arbitrary $a > 1$.

I tried looking up concentration bounds for sums of random variables, but there were many deficiencies, such as only applying for finite sums of random variables, requiring the distribution to be identical for each term in the series, and most painfully, requiring "moment conditions" on the distribution of the $X_i$ (e.g. bounded, sub-exponential, finite moments of some order). If possible I would like to avoid imposing conditions on the distribution of the $X_i$, but if it is truly impossible to provide a general bound in terms of the function $T$ I would accept a condition like $E[|X_i|^{2+\varepsilon}] < \infty$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$.

I have tried using various tools to solve this (the usual inequalities e.g. Markov and so forth) as well as tried to research to see if this question had been answered before, but to my dismay this particular question has either never been asked, or is buried in a sea of questions relating to the famous geometric distribution and sums of such random variables.

I would appreciate any help or hints! Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I don't see any actual work, just claims of "trying", with "dismay".  If nothing else, show your effort, even if it leads to a dead end. Sometimes the method might be right, but a simple error trips one up.  Any post with multiple claims: "I tried x, but..." when you fail to show your effort, and "then I tried y... but..." when you again fail to show your attempt, etc., only makes for a long post with  little substance.

Comment: @amWhy Thank you for the feedback - I am pretty new to posting questions here and I thought perhaps that would clutter my question and make it less clear. Some things I have tried:

Assuming $T(\cdot)$ is strictly decreasing, I have tried using Markov's inequality with the strictly increasing function $\frac{1}{T(\cdot)}$. This gets the term $T(u)$ in front but there is a multiplying expectation which I am not sure is finite.

I have tried using the characteristic function of the $X$ and the $X_i$, which will always exist for each. I could not find a simple way to make this useful, though.

Comment: No problem: but as I said, sometimes effort that seemingly ends in failure, might be on the right track.  Just take this advice for future use.  No harm done.

Comment: I have also shown by an "invariance" argument that $P(X > u) = E[T(u - \frac{1}{a}X)]$. This feels sort of on the right track, but I did not see how it was immediately useful as this seems to move the problem of characterizing the distribution of $X$ in terms of itself.

Comment: Indeed.  It seems clear you've spent quite a bit of time on this question!